# Radius of a circle as it travels under a function

Tags: calculus, geometry

I thought of this math problem yesterday, and I'm struggling to figure out how to solve it.

For any given function f(x), as circle *A* travels along the x-axis, it's radius is defined as the largest possible radius that is tangent to both f(x) and the x-axis, while not being secant to any portion of f(x). What's the equation that would represent the radius of circle *A* as it travels along the x-axis.

My idea was to use the smallest negative inverse derivative of f(x) that goes through the center of the circle *A*, but I have no idea how to determine where the distance from the x-axis to the center of the circle is at any given point.

How would one go about solving this?

Comment: For clarification purpose - could you add a simple graph?

Comment: What do you mean by "not being secant"?

Comment: Basically, what he means is that the circle should not intersect the function anywhere else apart from the point of tangency,